# How show the attributes of class in the UML Class Diagram reversed by MyEclipse 10?

Tags: java, uml, myeclipse

I'm trying to reverse class to UML class diagram in MyEclipse, but the diagram just shows functions except attributes. I need functions and attibutes, if it's possible, I would like to hide the arguments of functions. How should I do? pelase help me.
Thanks advance

Comment: btw, I use UML2.0 in MyEclipse

Answer (score 0):

In the properties for the diagram, there is a Presentation tab, which allows you to display either attributes or operations, or both attributes and operations. Seems like you have that set to hide attributes.

I don't know of a way to hide arguments. Remember that more than one operation might have the same name, so arguments are a way to distinguish between them. In fact, the complete signature of a method, in Java, defines the method, not just its name.

Comment: I can't find the relative Tabs. I use UML2.0 in MyEclipse 10. btw, is it a problem that only JavaBen will display it's attributes in Class Diagram ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using UML1. I'm not aware of any preferences or settings that allow you to do what you want. I'm not sure what you mean about JavaBeans. All classes used in reverse engineering should have their attributes included. To follow up this problem, please use http://www.myeclipseide.com/forums which is better suited to a comment/reply format.